# Issues measuring program execution time in Linux/Bash

Tags: linux, bash, time, runtime

Hopefully not a dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198597/measuring-a-programs-running-time)...

I'm trying to determine the curve of a specified program's runtime with the time function.

What I would like to do is automate this process to get several hundred points of data to graph in Excel, however I am getting different output when running in a Linux terminal vs a bash script.

Here is what I get when I run it from the terminal:

```
time program_1 500
> 0.004u 0.000s 0:00.00 0.0%   0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
```

and here is my bash script (first argument is the program, second is the number)

```
#!/bin/bash

time $1 $2
```

and here...my output is different, even though when I echo the above statement in a literal manner, it appears to be the exact same call.

```
> sh runner.sh program_1 500
> 0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed 400%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 3488maxresident)k0inputs+0outputs (0major+275minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Why the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there are actually 2 `time` commands, and one of them is built into bash. `man bash` for the one installed in `/usr/bin/time` and `help time` for the builtin. Use the absolute path in your script to get same behaviour.